# SQL Server Agent periodically stops executing SSIS jobs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

I'm currently having a issue on our SQL Server Agent, I have multiple SSIS packages running from a SSIS Catalogue. These packages are running through without any trouble but at random times during the day they all get stuck in a running status.

I have checked the SSIS catalogue's run history and connections and cant see that there is a request being sent through from SQL Agent to the catalogue to even kick off the job.

Does anyone know what the possible cause of this could be? The only way I have found to fix the issue is by restarting the SQL Agent. It will then start executing the SSIS packages again

Comment: Are you executing the packages at the same time or sequentially? We experienced similar problems when executing multiple packages at the same time - this leads to a deadlock in the SSIS catalogue and the execution ist not properly started...

Comment: @Tyron78 some are at the same time, but its not locking out since there's multiple packages that's not executing. To give you an idea I have roughly 70 different SSIS packages executing daily

Comment: @GeralP the question is: are the ones which are executed separately getting stuck as well? Example: if you execute package 1 separately and packages 2,3 and 4 at the same time, risks are high that 2, 3 and 4 get stuck due to deadlock situation on the SSIS - SSIS tries to create an execution per package and this might get stuck if performed at the same time. Are you executiong the packages in the "standard" way within SSIS (e.g. within a container) or via C# script task? In the first case try to reduce the number of parallel executions, in the second case use a delay of 500ms

Comment: @Tyron78 They are being executed separately, I tried cancelling all the jobs that are stuck manually from SQL agent and then executing them 1 at a time but the problem persists. I noticed that I can execute the packages from the catalogue itself and it runs through without an issue. What I find very strange is that if I go into the job execution history on the SSIS catalogue it doesn't even show an attempt to run at all.

Comment: so you have one Job per package? Did you consider building a steering package around the other packages? Additionally, check the user which you provides as executiong user in the job steps - are you using the same user you used for manual execution?

Comment: Is there something on the server itself that could cause SQL agent to not be able to connect to the catalogue for some reason?

Comment: @Tyron78 yes I have 1 job per package, what do you mean by steering package? The user that is executing the job is our dedicated SQL agent user on our domain, but I have set up a proxy account to impersonate my details so I can test using my own user which still does the same.

Comment: no, as far as I know the agent can not be blocked from access to the SSIS catalogue. The idea behind a steering package is: You define a new package within your solution which calls the other packages. You can place a sequence container in it and in this you place several `execute package` tasks, which are NOT connected to each other. Then you place a second sequence container and connect it with a preceding constraint to the first seq. container. Into this you place the next `execute package` tasks and so on. Then you define ONE job which calls the steering package.